# word request: treat in a unified manner

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a concise verb for "to treat in a unified manner". Alternatively, an alternative short adverb for "in a unified manner" is useful as well. Here is the context:

> With this new abstract theory, we can treat several phenomena in a unified manner.

Comment: Collectively...?

Comment: or globally ...?

Comment: "*This theory **generalizes** the observations we've made of several phenomena...*"

Answer (score 1):

How about "consistently"?

If you're open to keeping approximately the same number of words, "in the same way" is plainer English than "in a unified manner."

Answer (score 0):

> With this new abstract theory, we can **consolidate** several phenomena.

As the google tells us, **consolidate** can mean

> combine (a number of things) into a single more effective or coherent
>   whole

Answer (score 0):

> an alternative short adverb for "in a unified manner"

**systematically**

*With this new abstract theory, we can treat several phenomena* systematically."

Answer (score 0):

If I am talking about several distinct ideas being unified or integrated with each other I'd use **[Cohesive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cohesive)**.

"With this new abstract theory, we can treat several phenomena in a cohesive manner."